# jquerymobile: how to delete list items divider

Tags: jquery-mobile

I don't want to show lines / border between each list item of a `listview`. 
How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Nehatha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add your CSS. jQuery Mobile has CSS to mark up list elements which includes the borders, so simply override these defaults.

Comment: Thank you, I simply applied style="border-width: 0px;". It worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/KSTTQ/2/

JS

```
$('#noBorders').children().removeClass('ui-body-c');
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="content" > 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">List Items</li> 
            <li>Item #1</li> 
            <li>Item #2</li>
            <li>Item #3</li>
            <li>Item #4</li>
            <li>Item #5</li>
        </ul> 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="noBorders"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">List Items no borders</li> 
            <li>Item #6</li>
            <li>Item #7</li>
            <li>Item #8</li>
            <li>Item #9</li>
            <li>Item #10</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```